# Getting ANR every time When Loading Leadbolt Add

Tags: android, leadbolt

I am getting ANR every Time when App run while loading Leadbolt ads

```
                  myController = new AdController(this, "478326468");
             myController.loadAd();
```

When I remove the above line , it runs perfectly.

Logs :

```
  01-24 19:11:52.404: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.404: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.424: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.424: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.444: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.444: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.474: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.474: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.494: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.494: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.524: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.524: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.534: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 425K, 14% free 10109K/11719K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 36ms
01-24 19:11:52.544: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.544: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.554: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.554: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.574: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.574: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.594: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.594: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.624: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.624: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.644: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.644: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.664: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.664: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.684: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.684: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.934: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.934: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.964: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.964: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:52.974: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 10136K/11719K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 28ms
01-24 19:11:52.984: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:52.984: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.004: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.004: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.014: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.014: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.034: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.034: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.054: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.054: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.064: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.064: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.685: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.685: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.705: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.705: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.725: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.725: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.755: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.755: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.785: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.785: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.805: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 14% free 10137K/11719K, paused 14ms+13ms, total 51ms
01-24 19:11:53.805: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.805: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.825: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.825: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.845: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.845: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.875: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.875: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.895: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.895: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.915: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.915: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.945: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.945: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.965: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.965: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:53.985: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:53.985: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.005: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.005: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.035: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.035: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.045: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 14% free 10110K/11719K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 35ms
01-24 19:11:54.055: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.055: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.065: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.065: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.075: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.075: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.095: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.095: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.115: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.115: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.135: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.135: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.165: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.165: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.185: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.185: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.206: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.206: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.236: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.236: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.246: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 14% free 10110K/11719K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 29ms
01-24 19:11:54.256: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.256: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.276: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.276: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.286: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.286: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.306: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.306: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.326: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.326: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:11:54.346: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:11:54.346: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:02.033: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:02.033: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.350: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.350: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.380: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.380: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.400: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.400: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.410: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 14% free 10109K/11719K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 23ms
01-24 19:12:09.430: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.430: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.440: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.440: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.460: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.460: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:09.480: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:09.480: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.654: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.654: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.674: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.674: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.704: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.704: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.724: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.724: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.754: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.754: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.784: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.784: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.794: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 14% free 10134K/11719K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 28ms
01-24 19:12:12.804: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.804: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.814: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.814: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.834: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.834: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.854: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.854: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.874: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.874: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.894: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.894: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.914: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.914: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.934: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.934: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.964: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.964: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:12.984: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:12.984: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.024: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 14% free 10114K/11719K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 37ms
01-24 19:12:13.024: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.024: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.034: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.034: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.054: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.054: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.084: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.084: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.104: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.104: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.124: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.124: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.154: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.154: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.184: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.184: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.204: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.204: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.214: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.214: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.254: D/dalvikvm(3563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 14% free 10108K/11719K, paused 15ms+3ms, total 38ms
01-24 19:12:13.264: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.264: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.284: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.284: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.304: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.304: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.324: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.324: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-24 19:12:13.344: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-24 19:12:13.344: W/SingleClientConnManager(3563): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other web connections running in your app that could interfere with Leadbolts ad request?

Try to run your code as the very first thing in your app (in onCreate) and comment out any other application relevant code, especially code that makes use of web connections.